# How to set Button label in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, button

How to set Button label in Windows Phone? I cannot find text property or anything like that.

Comment: Property Content of Button is responsible for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Button.Content = "Your Label";

<Button Content="Your Label"/>
```